# Angularjs auto refresh does not stop on cancel

Tags: angularjs

I am refreshing a method using `$interval` to check for data. I am using a toggle switch to ON/OFF. By default it starts with ON and its refreshing. If i switch it OFF it goes to OFF state and after 5 seconds again moves to ON state and keep on refreshing. Why my `cancel()` is not invoked?

HTML

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus();"> </i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status ==false" ng-click="changeStatus();"> </i>
</div>
```

js

```
App.controller('Ctrl', [ '$scope', 'Details', '$interval', function($scope, Details, $interval  ) {

    $scope.availableDetailsTemp = [];
    $scope.availableDetails = [];

    init();  

    function init() {
        $scope.status = true;
        $scope.availableDetails = [];
        $scope.availableDetailsTemp = 
        Details.resource2.query(function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
                if (item) {
                    $scope.availableDetails.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
     }
     var myInterval = null;

     if ($scope.status = true) {
        myInterval = $interval(init, 5000);
     }          

     $scope.changeStatus = function(){
         $scope.status = !$scope.status;
         if ($scope.status = false) {
             $interval.cancel(myInterval);
         }  
     };
}]);
```

Comment: clearInterval(myInterval);

Comment: I tried giving it inside the false condition, but still the same

Comment: `$scope.status = false` should be `$scope.status === false` or simply `!$scope.status`. Make a similar change for `$scope.status = true` too.

Comment: After changing it stopped loading, but if i turn switch ON, refresh is not starting.

Comment: I added the true condition inside the changeStatus, its working. Is it right ? If so please post answer with explanation, I will accept. If its wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @Alex K please post an answer. I will accept it. I solved it only because of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) when you intended to use a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). In JavaScript, there are three similar-looking operators that can be easily confused: `=`, `==`, and `===`.

Here's what MDN says about the assignment operator `=`:

> Simple assignment operator which assigns a value to a variable. The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value.

So a statement of the form `if (x = false)` does this:

1. First, `x = false` *assigns* the value `false` to the variable `x`. Now `x` holds the value `false`.
2. The result of the assignment is the assigned value: `false`. That gets passed into the `if` statement as `if (false)`. So, the `if` statement doesn't pass.

Here's an example to show the assignment operator in action:

```js
var x;

if (x = true) {
  console.log('x = true passed! x is now ' + x);
}

if (x = 'banana') {
  console.log('x = banana passed! x is now ' + x);
}

if (x = false) {
  //You'll never get here!
}
else {
  console.log('x = false failed! x is now ' + x);
}
```

Oftentimes we only care whether a variable is a [truthy or falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). In those instances, we can omit the comparison operator entirely and simply evaluate the variable directly in the `if` condition.

So in your case, we can change the conditions to:

```
if ($scope.status) {
  //$scope.status is truthy
  myInterval = $interval(init, 5000);
}           

$scope.changeStatus = function(){
    $scope.status = !$scope.status;
    if (!$scope.status) {
      //$scope.status is falsy
      $interval.cancel(myInterval);
    }   
}
```